# Uninstall Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to Mangeto, i just installed magento few days before and started learning from online sources, then i required to install sample data. i read that i should install sample data with the installation of magento, but that i did not do, i did not install sample data while installing magento.

Please let me know how to install sample data on already installed magento or let me know how to delete the old magento so that i could install fresh magento with sample data..

i am using WAMP server on windows Platform

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sample data means any module or extension?

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR - sample data means whichever is available at www.magentocommerce.com › Knowledge Base http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce18-ee113/ht_magento-ce-sample.data.html

Comment: Install new magento with sample data. If you want to delete magento delete magento folder and used database.

Comment: means directly deleting directory under 'www' folder. i have magento folder under www. and droping the related database.. Correct ??

Comment: Yes, delete magento folder and database

Comment: ok, i will do it then, can you please share the good tutorials to start with magento for beginners, please add your comment as answer..

Comment: or can i add themes in magento ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in uninstaller for Magento.

If you followed best practices while developing Magento, all of your Magento-related files should be located under the same root folder in your filesystem, and all Magento-related database tables should be located in the same database.

If that's the case, uninstalling is as simple as deleting the files in the filesystem:

`sudo rm -rf <magento root dir>`

And dropping the database associated with Magento:

`mysqladmin -u[username] -p[password] drop [database]`

If you can't remember the name of the database your Magento installation uses, you can find that in `app/etc/local.xml` in the dbname node. You'll also find relevant login information there.

If you placed files or tables outside the bounds of Magento's root directory and database, you'll have to identify them and delete them manually.